# A short riddle of violence and peace

Tags: riddle

Raise yourself to strike me down,
and I will defeat you.
I promise.
You lose; I win.

Seen through lenses tinted by human anguish, I could be mistaken for a goose-stepping Nazi at your BLM march.

But,
I’m not evil;
I’m vanquished by the slightest gesture of peace and love.

Who am I?

Who are you?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! :-)

Comment: Nice riddle, how about rhyming? Raise yourself to strike me down, but it's me who will take the crown. Through lenses tinted by anguish you might see, that I am gesturing a goose-stepping Nazi. But I’m not evil, to say the least, as I’m vanquished by the gesture of peace. Answer my questions, I have two: Who am I, and who are you?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are

> Paper!

And this is a game of

> Rock, Paper, Scissors!

---

Raise yourself to strike me down,
and I will defeat you.
I promise.
You lose, I win

> Raise your fist as a **rock**, and paper will defeat you

Seen through lenses tinted by human anguish, I could be mistaken for a goose-stepping Nazi at your BLM march.

> **Paper** is holding out your hand flat, and this could be mistaken for a Nazi salute, and the BLM symbol is an uphold fist. Paper beating rock could be mistaken for this ✋

But,
I’m not evil.
I’m vanquished by the slightest gesture of peace and love.

> Paper is vanquished by **scissors** which resembles the peace sign ✌️

Who are you?

> You are 'Paper'...

Who am I?

> ... and I am 'Rock'!

Comment: Yes! I'm not surprised at how quick that was :)

Comment: @Jolenealaska very nice riddle!! A clever spin on a well known game

Comment: Thanks! That was fun. My next one will be tougher :)

Comment: Heh, weirdly I was sure that this would be something political. The surface reading, and knowing @Jolenealaska a bit, fooled me completely :-P

Comment: @Randal'Thor HA! A bit of that was intended.